# Replace server name with fake server name in response header in fastapi

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I am using uvicorn as server to run app using fast api. While executing endpoint url in Swagger, following message is shown in response header of server response.

```
 content-length: 122 
 content-type: application/json 
 date: Sat12 Dec 2020 10:18:55 GMT 
 server: uvicorn
```

How to change server name to new name as server : firstproject?
Following code concatenates server name unciorn with new name

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def add_custom_header(request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    response.headers['server'] = 'firstproject'
    return response
```

This gives the following output

```
content-length: 122 
 content-type: application/json 
 date: Sat12 Dec 2020 10:19:33 GMT 
 server: uvicornfirstproject
```

How to change server name to server : firstproject in response header?

**EDIT**

In start_server.py

```
 import uvicorn

from app.main import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("start_server:app --header server:firstproject", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)
```

gives following error

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [15256] using statreload
ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Attribute "app --header server:firstproject" not found in module "start_server".
```

I run the code from Visual studio

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set a custom header when running uvicorn.

> `--header TEXT`Specify custom default HTTP response headers as a Name:Value pair

When you run it like this, it will override the default server name.

```sh
uvicorn my_app:app --header server:firstproject
```

If you are running uvicorn from a python file. You need to pass them as tuple inside a list.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("my_app:app", headers=[("server", "firstproject")])
```

Comment: I have edited question to show error after adding as you suggest .

Comment: You are running it wrong, i updated my answer.

Comment: It worked in localhost. When I push same code to Linode and run then again uvicorn is shown in server name instead of fake server name firstproject

Comment: Hmm, it's strange. Are you load balancing the traffic between two revisions?

Comment: Sorry .I got response in linode too  after adding both passing tuple (python code) and uvicorn my_app:app --header server:firstproject (during run)
Thank you for quick response

Answer (score 8):

In case of you need to "delete" the "server" header, you can use option `--no-server-header`

```
uvicorn my_app:app --no-server-header
```

If you are running uvicorn from a python file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('my_app:app', server_header=False)
```