# How to change/suppress server header with gunicorn and uvicorn worker class?

Tags: python, gunicorn, uvicorn, asgi

I'm running my python asgi application with `gunicorn` and `uvicorn` worker class with this command line:

`unicorn -c gunicorn_conf.py my.asgi:application -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker`

I want to obfuscate the `server` HTTP header.

The [uvicorn `--no-server-header` flag](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#http) seems ignored by `gunicorn`.

How to change/suppress server http header when running `gunicorn` and `uvicorn` worker class ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace server name with fake server name in response header in fastapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65263792/replace-server-name-with-fake-server-name-in-response-header-in-fastapi)

Comment: @rzlvmp I think it's not really the same question, but your answer seems ok. I'm doing a test before accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

You may extend `UvicornWorker` class by overriding [`CONFIG_KWARGS`](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/411dd87ed0574a0581d2b7e5ff79de74ed3c9868/uvicorn/workers.py#L20):

- `app.py`

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from uvicorn.workers import UvicornWorker
from os import environ


class ServerlessUvicornWorker(UvicornWorker):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if environ.get('CUSTOM_SERVER', None) is None:
            self.CONFIG_KWARGS["server_header"] = False
        else:
            self.CONFIG_KWARGS["headers"] = [("server", environ['CUSTOM_SERVER'])]
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

In this case command like:

```bash
gunicorn app:app -k app.ServerlessUvicornWorker
```

will hide `Server` header

And

```bash
CUSTOM_SERVER='COOL_SERVER' gunicorn app:app -k app.ServerlessUvicornWorker
```

will rename `Server` header to `COOL_SERVER`:

```
$ wget -S --spider localhost:8000

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2023-04-18 23:14:02--  http://localhost:8000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
  date: Tue, 18 Apr 2023 14:14:02 GMT
  server: COOL_SERVER
  content-length: 31
  content-type: application/json
Remote file does not exist -- broken link!!!
```

Comment: I'm stuck with   `File "/home/python/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 569, in spawn_worker
    worker = self.worker_class(self.worker_age, self.pid, self.LISTENERS,
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: @sgargel I have to see code or reproducible example to be able help

Comment: https://github.com/sgargel/gunicorn-uvicorn-server-header

Comment: there is different file structure in github repo. Here is no `app` folder in my example and python file is calling `app.py` (and yours is `main.py`). You should fix `Dockerfile`: `ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "app.main:app", "-k", "app.main.ServerlessUvicornWorker"]`

Comment: Yes @rzlvmp you are right. In my repo the classpath was wrong. Thanks. I'm still getting error when `server_header` is False with:  `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/workers.py", line 59, in __init__`
    `self.config = Config(**config_kwargs)`
`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'server_header'`

Comment: Fixed! Thanks. It needs `uvicorn >= 0.15.0` !